# error in calling function from another component on button click

Tags: reactjs

In my ReactJS code, by using refs, I am calling addRecord and deleteRecord functions of Action component inside of the View component on respective button click. But I am getting an error (posted below). Please tell what is the wrong with my code?

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteRecord' of undefined
    at new View (index.js:32602)
    at index.js:28264
...
```

**View.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Action from './Action.jsx';

class View extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.refs.actionHandler.deleteRecord = this.refs.actionHandler.deleteRecord.bind(this);
        this.refs.actionHandler.addRecord = this.refs.actionHandler.addRecord.bind(this);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.props.store.map((eachRecord) => (
                    <li className="list-group-item" key={eachRecord.id}>{eachRecord.name}
                    <button style={{float:'right'}} onClick={this.refs.actionHandler.deleteRecord(eachRecord)}>Delete</button></li>))}
                </ul>
                <input type="text" ref="inputElement"/>
                <button onClick={this.refs.actionHandler.addRecord(this.refs.inputElement)}>Add</button>
                <Action ref="actionHandler" store={this.props.store} updateStore={this.props.updateStore} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default View;
```

**Action.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Dispatcher from './Dispatcher.jsx';

let recordId=3;

class Action extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Dispatcher updateStore={this.props.updateStore} ref="dispatcher" />
            </div>
        );
    };

    addRecord(input) {
        const inputElement = input;
        const text = inputElement.value.trim();
        inputElement.value = '';
        inputElement.focus();

        ++recordId;
        var newRecord = {name: text, id: recordId};
        var newStore = this.props.store;
        newStore.push(newRecord);

        this.refs.dispatcher.dispatchChanges(newStore);
    };

    deleteRecord(record) {
        var newStore = this.props.store.filter(r => r !== record);
        this.refs.disptacher.dispatchChanges(newStore);
    }
}

export default Action;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your code and I don't see where you're passing in `deleteRecord`

```
<Action ref="actionHandler" 
store={this.props.store} 
updateStore={this.props.updateStore} />
```

Comment: Please see this question for greater explainination of the issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445667/calling-a-function-using-ref-value-in-reactjs-throws-error?noredirect=1#comment79849240_46445667