# calling a function using ref value in ReactJS throws error

Tags: reactjs

I have been learning ReactJS and I have written a simple program in which some records are being displayed in a list and each record can be deleted by clicking its delete button. There are three components in my code. Store is calling View component for displaying records and View is calling Action component for deleting any record.

Now the problem is that when I press delete button to delete any record, I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteRecord' of undefined`error. So please tell what can be the issue in my code?

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteRecord' of undefined
    at onClick (index.js:32647)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (index.js:7735)
    at executeDispatch (index.js:7519)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (index.js:7542)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (index.js:5512)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (index.js:5523)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachAccumulated (index.js:11731)
    at Object.processEventQueue (index.js:5723)
    at runEventQueueInBatch (index.js:26646)
```

***Code:***

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "app"></div>
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Store from './Store.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Store />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**Store.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import View from './View.jsx';

class Store extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            records: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'First User',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Second User',
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Third User'
                }
            ]
        }

        this.updateStore = this.updateStore.bind(this);
    };

    updateStore(newState) {
        this.setState({records: newState});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <View store={this.state.records} updateStore={this.updateStore} />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Store;
```

**View.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Action from './Action.jsx';

class View extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.props.store.map((eachRecord,index) =>
                        <ListItem key={index} actionHandler={this.refs.actionHandler} singleRecord={eachRecord} />
                    )}
                </ul>
                <Action ref="actionHandler" store={this.props.store} updateStore={this.props.updateStore} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li className="list-group-item">
                {this.props.singleRecord.name}
                <button style={{float:'right'}} onClick={() => this.props.actionHandler.deleteRecord(this.props.singleRecord)}>Delete</button>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

export default View;
```

**Action.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class Action extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    };

    deleteRecord(record) {
        var newStore = this.props.store.filter(eachR => eachR !== record);
        this.props.updateStore(newStore);
    }
}

export default Action;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error in calling function from another component on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416958/error-in-calling-function-from-another-component-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `refs` object before react attached the component's refs.
It's been recommended by react to not use `refs` like that anymore, instead use `ref` with callback:
`<div ref={ref => this.divRef = ref} />`
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

But in your case, you can do it just by passing callbacks to the component and without using `refs` at all.
First of all, it seems that the `<Actions />` component is unnecessary.
You can just pass the callback function to the `<ListItem />` component:

```
class ListItem extends React.Component {

  deleteRecord(record) {
    var newStore = this.props.store.filter(eachR => eachR !== record);
    this.props.updateStore(newStore);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item">
        {this.props.singleRecord.name}
        <button style={{ float: 'right' }} onClick={() => this.deleteRecord(this.props.singleRecord)}>Delete</button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

now, this component will know what to do when you click on this button.

Note that now you will need to pass all of this props to the `<ListItem />` component like this:

`<ListItem key={index} store={this.props.store} updateStore={this.props.updateStore} singleRecord={eachRecord} />`

For a better approach and less props to pass you might want to put the `deleteRecord` function at the top level component and just pass down this component.
More on that you can read here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: for some reasons I have to use `<Action />` component. Can you please suggest a solution without changing the structure of the code?